# Centering labels with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm trying to center labels using MigLayout and I'm having a difficult time. Here's what I'd like the labels to look like:

- |   [label1] [label2] [label3] [label4] [label5]  |
- |  ............ [label6][label7][label8]  ............|          |

I'd like to:

1. Limit the number of labels to five per row and I think I can use *wrap 5*.
2. Center the labels inside the JPanels

I have labeled sections on the main JPanel with subpanels, like this:

- Section 1
- [subpanel with labels]
- Section 2
- [subpanel with labels]

There's no problem with centering if there's only a single label because I do this:

```
myPanel.add(label, "align center, wrap");
```

Unfortunately, if I add more than one they just don't center. I've gone through the MigLayout Cheat Sheet but it's like going through an API without fully understanding how it all works and I haven't been able to find any good tutorials out there. I'd like to become proficient with MigLayout, so a good tutorial would probably do the trick.

I'd be grateful for your help.

Comment: slightly confused: why do you have columns if you don't want to fill them? Anyway, show a SSCCE of what exactly you are trying

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you want but this is my guess:

```
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
panel.add(label3);
panel.add(label4);
panel.add(label5, "wrap");
panel.add(label6, "al 100%");
panel.add(label7, "align center");
panel.add(label8);

frame.pack();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make miglayout with center column constraint and you can add it by cell no.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("","[center][center][center][center][center]","[]"));

JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label2");
JLabel label3 = new JLabel("label3");
JLabel label4 = new JLabel("label4");
JLabel label5 = new JLabel("label5");

panel.add(label1, "cell 0 0");
panel.add(label2, "cell 1 0");
panel.add(label3, "cell 2 0");
panel.add(label4, "cell 3 0");
panel.add(label5, "cell 4 0");
f.getContentPane().add(panel);
```